# How to log responses of an api request in terminate function of a Laravel middleware

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.4, laravel-5.5, laravel-5.6

I need to log responses of each api request. For that I created a middleware and used ResponseTrait in terminate function of that middleware. Everything works fine until I use the status function of ResponseTrait. I tried both $this->status and self::status but nothing worked. It says syntax error when I use this function. Following is the code of my middleware.

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use Spatie\HttpLogger\LogWriter;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Http\ResponseTrait;

class logger implements LogWriter
{
   use ResponseTrait;
   /**
    * Handle an incoming request.
    *
    * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
    * @param  \Closure  $next
    * @return mixed
    */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
      return $next($request);
    }
    public function terminate($request)
    {
      $responseCode = $this->status();
    }
 }
```

Comment: ` $responseCode = $this->status();` this is a status code which you are to user.

Comment: Can you please be more clear@AdnanMumtaz

Comment: this is a status code which you are  returning to user from your controller..

Comment: can you please post the error

Comment: It just says Syntax error. nothing else@AdnanMumtaz

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response status comes from the result of `$next($request);`, so you'd need to reference it like:

```
$response = $next($request);
$status = $response->status();
return $response;
```

Comment: I tried the same approach with some difference and its working for me thank you so much.